# Rstudio will not knit

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

Rstudio will not knit. I have been using it for a few weeks in a course.

When I try to knit it executes until it comes to some code and it stops. The code is

> ggplot(data = gss, aes(x = year, fill = degree)) +
>    geom_bar()

The message is

> could not find function "ggplot"

This happens with other functions as well. With the code commented out is will run and produce an HTML file.

I have reinstalled R and Rstudio twice. I have had difficulty with my AV software (Bitdefender) blocking the install of some of the apps. The software is a new version updated a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: I have loaded tinyverse and it (ggplot) executes in the markdown file.

Answer (score 3):

Please load the package *in the document* (R Markdown? You didn't say) before you use any functions in it, e.g., `library(ggplot2)`.