# Issue when knitting: could not find function `ggplot`

Tags: r, knitr

I am using the Knit functionality. I have been reading the manual, but I am still confused.

When I click *File --> Knit the document*, I get the error:

> > could not find function "`ggplot`".

Any thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look at the [Help]. I think your question has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47685616/rstudio-will-not-knit).